# JavaFX: Removing Text from a Group causes Exception

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I place an `ImageView` and a `Text` inside a `Group`. When I try to remove the `Text`, I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator$VetoableIteratorDecorator.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator$VetoableIteratorDecorator.hasNext(Unknown Source)
    at fjr.tool.TestMake$2$2$1.handle(TestMake.java:67)
    at fjr.tool.TestMake$2$2$1.handle(TestMake.java:1)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
```

This is my code:

```
package fjr.tool;

import java.io.File;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestMake extends Application{

    int num  = 2; 
    Group[] groupCollection = new Group[num];
    ImageView view[] = new ImageView[num]; 

    String url[] = new String[]{
            "E:/testimage/1.jpg", 
            "E:/testimage/2.jpg"
    };

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Group root = new Group(); 
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 400));  

        HBox box = new HBox(){{
            setSpacing(10); 
        }};



        box.getChildren().addAll(new VBox(){{
            setSpacing(5); 
            getChildren().addAll(new  Button("ADD LABEL"){{
                setPrefWidth(100);
                setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {  
                        int yy = 0 ; 
                        for(int i=0; i< num; i++){
                            double width = view[i].getImage().getWidth(); 
                            Text text = new Text("AA"); 
                            text.setTranslateX(width - 20);
                            text.setTranslateY(yy); 
                            groupCollection[i].getChildren().add(text); 
                            yy += view[i].getImage().getHeight(); 
                        }
                    }
                });
            }}, new Button("REMOVE LABEL"){{
                setPrefWidth(100); 
                setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {  
                        for(int i=0; i< num;i++){
                            Group g = groupCollection[i]; 
                            for(Node node : g.getChildren()){
                                if(node instanceof Text){
                                    g.getChildren().remove(node); 
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }}); 
        }}, 

        new ScrollPane(){{
            setPrefSize(370, 300);
            setContent( new VBox(){{
                setSpacing(5);
                for(int i=0; i< num; i++){
                    final int j = i; 
                    groupCollection[i] = new Group(view[i] = new ImageView() {{
                        setImage(new Image(new File(url[j]).toURI().toString()));
                    }}); 
                    getChildren().add(groupCollection[i]); 
                }

            }});
        }}
                ); 

        root.getChildren().add(box); 
        stage.show(); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't directly modify a List while you're iterating though it. The iterator gets confused.

Do

```
List<Node> nodesToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
for(Node node : g.getChildren()){
    if(node instanceof Text){
        nodesToRemove.add(node);
    }
}

g.getChildren().removeAll(nodesToRemove);
```

or (better):

```
for (Iterator<Node> iterator = g.getChildren().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    if (iterator.next() instanceof Text) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

or, in Java8,

```
g.getChildren().removeIf(node -> node instanceof Text);
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure which is best; the second version (using iterator.remove()) only makes one pass through the list of children, but will invoke the listeners to the list every time a node is removed. (This isn't as bad as it sounds; it'll just be flagged as invalid and then layouts will be computed once on the next pulse). The first and third essentially do two passes through the list, one to flag which nodes to remove, and one to remove them; however the listeners only get notified once, on the bulk removal.